# Multiple hydride shifts

Tags: organic-chemistry

Can we have multiple hydride or methanide shifts? Specially in the case where after first shift it becomes less stable and after the second shift it becomes more stable.

For example, the first step of acid catalysed dehydration of 3-methylbutan-1-ol. The step in which H+ is added to the hydroxy group and it departs leaving a carbocation.

Comment: Could you be more specific and provide an example.

Comment: @user55119 Please check now, I have also stated an example.

Comment: @RahulVerma What about the example above?                  I'm telling to check the example written in the question. Can the carbonation have multiple Hydride shifts?

Comment: hydration or dehydration?

Comment: @SafdarFaisal sorry dehydration i will correct it

Comment: @SafdarFaisal please check now.

Comment: In this given scenario, after the first hydride shift, the abstraction of H takes place from C3. so no shift takes place. Even if it did shift it would give an carbocation with the same stability

Comment: @SafdarFaisal OK cool, but what if i had 3-methylpentan-1-ol. Then the most stable structure would be formed after the second Hydride shift.

Comment: One more thing to be considered is the fact that rearrangement only takes place if the new carbocation is more stable so your first statement is flawed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110487/discussion-between-safdar-faisal-and-harrison-wells).

Comment: @SafdarFaisal OK got it.

Comment: This may help you https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/24604/what-is-the-maximum-extent-of-a-hydride-shift-to-form-the-most-stable-carbocatio

Comment: This answer is related to your question https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/27930/95066

Answer (score 1):

Yours is a primary alcohol and it has $\beta$ hydrogen atoms also. Thus, it will undergo $\pu E2$ mechanism. In this mechanism removal of protonated hydroxyl group and $\beta ~\pu H$ happen at once (in a single step). Therefore, there will be no scope of hydride shifting.

You may compare this with the dehydration of [*neo*-pentyl alcohol](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/136715/dehydration-of-primary-alcohols-without-a-%ce%b2-hydrogen).